# Prevent the LaunchScreen to show when App loads from the URL Scheme - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

**1)** I am invoking the App via URL Scheme (AppName:// ), it loads but it first Displays the Launch Screen (sliding in from right to left) first, then displays the specific view.

**2)** If I invoke it via Universal Link (https:// ), the App loads but DOES NOT display the Launch Screen, simply shows the specific view. Which is good and exactly the behaviour what I want.

**so can I prevent the Launch Screen to show up when it loads app from the URL Scheme in case (1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is closed (i.e. terminated, fully closed, not in memory) then whenever the app launches (from any type of URL) the `Launch Screen` will always be displayed before the app opens.

Make sure you are launching each time from a fully terminated app. You should see that it behaves in the same way each time.

If you are using the Launch Screen properly then this will make it look like the app is opening very quickly and give the user an impression of very fast app performance.

If you are using the Launch Screen as a way to display some sort of branding or splash screen then it will also show. Except now as a user you get the impression of an app that has some sort of loading screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved the mystery.